# How to get screen width and height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-activity, android-widget

I tried to use following code to get screen width and height in android app development:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
```

but I got **NullPointerException** for my `display`, why? how to get screen width and height then?

Comment: Where do you place these 3 lines? Maybe the default Display is not ready when you code is executed. Please post the code context. Try to call this in onCreate() of your Activity.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a helper class, that is not an Activity?

Comment: If one of these fixed your issue, you should accept an answer.

Comment: It would be nice if one of these answers were marked as correct.

Comment: Don't use `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()`, you cannot guarantee if you are the current display.

Answer (score 133):

If you're calling this outside of an Activity, you'll need to pass the context in (or get it through some other call).  Then use that to get your display metrics:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

UPDATE: With API level 17+, you can use [`getRealSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize(android.graphics.Point)):

```
Point displaySize = new Point();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(displaySize);
```

If you want the *available* window size, you can use [`getDecorView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getDecorView()) to calculate the available area by subtracting the decor view size from the real display size:

```
Point displaySize = new Point();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(displaySize);

Rect windowSize = new Rect();
ctivity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(windowSize);

int width = displaySize.x - Math.abs(windowSize.width());
int height = displaySize.y - Math.abs(windowSize.height());
return new Point(width, height);
```

[`getRealMetrics`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealMetrics(android.util.DisplayMetrics)) may also work (requires API level 17+), but I haven't tried it yet:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.GetWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(metrics);
```

Comment: Good answer. Please add the possibility to use getResources() without context.

Comment: @Kostanos As [getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources()) is a an abstract method on the Context class, you can't  use it without a Context. If you're in an Activity you can just call `getResources()`; if you're in a view, you can use `getContext().getResources()`. If neither of these work for you and you don't want to pass in a Context, see [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277011/getresources-from-static-method-without-context) for an alternative solution. Hope that helps!

Comment: You are right, it worked on the AndEngine Activities classes, but probably won't work on the default Activity class from SDK. Thanks.

Comment: @Kostanos It will work for any Activity, but only because Activity extends Context.

Comment: This is the answer, not sure why @Leem will not accept this or atleast one of the answers..

Comment: `height ` seems higher than the visible screen,how to get the real height of the screen.

Comment: @zionpi see update for an alternative way to get the available area.

Comment: if context doesn't exists, use `getApplicationContext()` instead.

Comment: Don't use `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()`, you cannot guarantee if you are the current display. The original answer was more correct than the edited one.

Answer (score 41):

Within an activity, you can call:

```
int width = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

When you're in a View, then you need to get the Context first:

```
int width = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
int height = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
```

This will work in all Android version, available since API 1, and never deprecated.

Comment: getApplicationContext() is used to get the context from Fragment, not from View. From view it would be getContext() instead.

Comment: @OliverHausler getContext will work too, only if you're in a view. getApplicationContext will work both in view and fragment, and in an activity too. It basically gives you the context of overall application, what's more important is to get the context first before calling resources to get pixel size. Please provide a strong reason for down-voting if you have any.

Comment: I have not down-voted anything, I have only commented that what you have stated is incorrect, and it is. "When you're in a View, then you need to get the Context first" -> `int width = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;` does not work from within a view.

Comment: It should, it does. Try correctly, like all other up-voters did.

Comment: Check the reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext() and/or try it. There is no getApplicationContext() method in view.

Answer (score 19):

From service:

```
Display  display= ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 15):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 13):

Try via `context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` if you have a context available.

Comment: could you please be more specific? I mean what's next?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources(), so normally an activity.

Comment: @Leem next you put it in a variable , and you can get widthPixels (for width) and heightPixels (for height) directly from the variable.

Answer (score 7):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

i guess the code which you wrote is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        Point size = new Point();
        try {
            this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
            screenWidth = size.x;
            screenHeight = size.y;
        } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
             screenHeight = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
             screenWidth=this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        }

    } else {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    }
```

Comment: but the code is slightly incorrect: getRealSize was added in API 17

Answer (score 3):

Try with the following code to get width and height of screen

```
int widthOfscreen =0;
int heightOfScreen = 0;
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        try {
            ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getMetrics(dm);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
         widthOfscreen  = dm.widthPixels;
heightOfScreen  = dm.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WindowManager w = getWindowManager();
Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
d.getMetrics(metrics);

Log.d("WIDTH: ", String.valueOf(d.getWidth()));
Log.d("HEIGHT: ", String.valueOf(d.getHeight()));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
       /*
        *DisplayMetrics: A structure describing general information about a display, such as its size, density, and font scaling.
        * */

 DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

       int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
       int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    int scrWidth  = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int scrHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

Comment: Hi, your post has been flagged as "low quality", probably because it consists solely of code. You could massively improve your answer by providing an explanation of exactly how and why this answers the question?

Comment: it returns width and height in pixels or not

Answer (score 0):

```
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int screenWidth = display.getWidth();
int screenHeight = display.getHeight();
Log.d("Tag", "Getting Width >> " + screenWidth);
Log.d("Tag", "Getting Height >> " + screenHeight);
```

This worked properly in my application

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way using function

```
private int[] getScreenSIze(){
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int h = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        int w = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        int[] size={w,h};
        return size;

    }
```

on button click or on your create function add the following code

```
int[] screenSize= getScreenSIze();
        int width=screenSize[0];
        int height=screenSize[1];
        screenSizes.setText("Phone Screen sizes \n\n  width = "+width+" \n Height = "+height);
```

Answer (score 0):

below answer support api level below and above 10

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            Point size = new Point();
            try {
                this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(size);
                screenWidth = size.x;
                screenHeight = size.y;
            } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
                 screenHeight = this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
                 screenWidth=this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            }

        } else {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
            screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        }
```