# how to show different Numbers of columns in a single listview in portrait and landscape mode android?

Tags: android, listview

can any one tell me it is possible to show different number of columns in  listview

For Example:- when i see listview in portrait mode it shows 3 columns and when i see listview in landscape mode it shows 4 columns  . i try to do it but my solutions doesn't work for me , i define to different layout for protrait in layout folder and landscape in layout-land folder but it doesn't seens to work for me .

```
Can any one tell me is it possible to achive this . 

And one More thing it possible to execute some code by checking 

For Example:-  if(this is android phone){

                  execute this code;
                 }

                if(this is android tablet){

                        execute this code;
                     }

 like iphone and ipad developer do 

                   if(this is iphone )
                   {
                    execute this code ;
                      }



                   if(this is ipad )
                   {
                    execute this code ;
                      }
```

because i same application is used in both phone and tablet and some one wants to show different things in phones and different in tablets .

```
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below link for tutorial

http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/

Thanks..!

Comment: thanks for replying but i dont want this , i want same listview with different numbers of columns like when i use my app i portrait mode it shows 3 columns and in landscape it shows 4 columns .

Answer (score 0):

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 int width = metrics.widthPixels;
 int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

this gives the dimensions of the screen and based on these values you can determine if it is a tablet..
[See this link to know how to get dimensions of your device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520718/how-to-get-screen-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0):

Create more layouts with same name in /res/layout

After selecting root element click "Next" and then choose one of the Available qualifiers (orientation) and define listView with its properties.

Comment: i do it like this doesn't seems to work . when i start my app in portrait mode it shows as i expected but when i immediatlly turn it to landscape it not shows the containt as i expected

Comment: Tr<y not to put portrait layout in /res/layout, put it in /res/layout-port and landscape layout in /res/layout-land. And delete default layout from /res/layout..

Comment: Same problem as i face before