# getResources() from static method, without context

Tags: android, resources, android-context

I'm working on a `SQLiteOpenHelper` from which I'll read databases via static methods (since the databases are shared anyway). Is it possible to get the application context to something like:

```
public static final Context context = XXX;
```

It should be possible right? Since I'm obviously only calling from the current app and both resources and databases are shared inside the app.

To be clear: I want to access Resources and the `SQLiteDatabases` (if I happen to be wrong about the context approach).

Is it possible to achieve?

**Edit:**
Is it possible to get the context from inside something like this (without passing it as a parameter)

```
public class foo{
    foo(){
        XXX.getResources();
    }
}
```

**Edit2:**
Trying @britzl:s fist idea

```
public class SpendoBase extends Application{
private static Context context;
public SpendoBase(){
    System.out.println("SPENDOBASE: " + this);
    System.out.println("SPENDOBASE: " + this.getBaseContext());
}
public static Context getContext(){
    return this.context;
}

}
```

How do i get hold of the context? Either in the constructor or form the `getContext();`

Ps the `getBaseContext()` returns null, and `getApplicationContext` thows a `nullPointerException`.

Comment: Do you want to access Resources without have a context ?

Comment: if possible, alternatively (if it exists) get a 'supercontext' which is shared by the entire app (which i can get a hold of with out passing it as argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three possible solutions to your problem:

1. Create your own subclass of Application and set that as your application class in the manifest file. In your subclass you could have a static getInstance() method that would provide you with the application context (and thus Resources) from anywhere within your application. Example:

   ```
   public class BaseApplication extends Application {

       private static BaseApplication instance;

       public BaseApplication() {
           super();
           instance = this;
       }

       public static BaseApplication getInstance() {
           return instance;
       }
   }
   ```

   And in AndroidManifest.xml:

   ```
   <application android:name="com.example.BaseApplication" ...>
       ...activities
   </application>
   ```
2. Pass a context to any calls you make in your SQLiteOpenHelper
3. Inject the Resources instance using dependency injection

Comment: 1. Sounds interesting, i'll look in to it    
2. Is the mess i'm trying to get straight atm   
3. Not quite sure i follow? :)

Comment: I'm trying to your first idea. I'm adding the code in the question, could you please help me to get a hold of the context from either the constructor or a static method call

Comment: Updated with an example for #1

Comment: Thank you! This will enable me to build a lot nicer structure :D

Comment: Personally I would have preferred a design that didn't require static access like that, but I'm glad it worked out in your case!

Comment: :) Why not? i don't REQUIRE it but ended upp with passing around contexts everywhere -.- But this is my fist bigger android project so i'd love you to elaborate.

Comment: If it's a large project there are benefits of using something like dependency injection. It can be used to greatly simplify unit testing but it's also a very powerful way of untangling dependencies. By using dependency injection you don't really have to worry about passing dependency Foo to class Bar or a Context to a SQLiteOpenHelper. The tedious passing of dependencies via constructors, setters or factories are done automatically once a dependency graph has been built. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: Also, for Android there's RoboGuice (https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice) for Android specific dependency injection (Contexts, Views, Extras etc). I've used RoboGuice in several project and it's very helpful. I have however ended up using plain old Guice and added Android specific injection myself (I don't like having to inherit from RoboActivity, RoboFragment etc).