# RelativeLayout height fill_parent doesn't work in item listview layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i have item listview layout with relative layout , but  when i'm set "fill_parent" height, it's seem not fill, how make it ?

this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_full"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"        
        android:background="@drawable/inbox_interface" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/favorite_anim"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/favorite_anime"
        android:src="@drawable/favorite_active" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lay_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/act_item_list"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/avatardetail"
            android:textColor="#6495ed"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username"
            android:layout_below="@+id/username"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:textColor="#555555"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/act_item_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/act_item_list"
            android:src="@drawable/act_list" />

        <com.droidersuin.project.utils.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatardetail"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar_user" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/isi_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lay_top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/judul"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textColor="#6495ed"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/id_tulisan"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/judul"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/id_tulisan"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/kordinat_lokasi"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/avatar"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/judul_seo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/kordinat_lokasi"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/status_gambar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/judul_seo"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gambar_tulisan_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/status_gambar"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/gambar_tulisan"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/judul"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
                android:contentDescription="@string/gambar_tulisan"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/detail_droidersuin" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sekilas_isi"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/gambar_tulisan"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gambar_tulisan"
                android:layout_below="@+id/judul"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gambar_tulisan"
                android:textColor="#555555"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/CommentLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dibaca"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:textColor="#555555"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/reader"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/reader"
                android:src="@drawable/reader" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/jmlh_komentar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:textColor="#555555"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:typeface="sans" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_komentar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ic_komentar"
                android:src="@drawable/comment" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/action_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/isi_layout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:clickable="false" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/favorite"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/button_action_indicator"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button_favorite"
            android:src="@drawable/favorite_noactive" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comment"
            android:background="@drawable/button_action_indicator"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button_share"
            android:src="@drawable/share" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/favorite"
            android:background="@drawable/button_action_indicator"
            android:contentDescription="@string/button_comment"
            android:src="@drawable/komentar" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the problem is here , the linearlayout not fill height , but width no problem ,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"        
        android:background="@drawable/inbox_interface" >
```

if it is run on the phone, even like this

[image]

the view just looks line black line

but I want to look like this

[image]

sorry for my english

Comment: no need to set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in list item..

Comment: sorry, i edited my question, height is fill_parent but nit work

Comment: The list knows its width, but the height is not known so `match_parent`/`fill_parent` is most of the times ignored

Comment: so snap what u want ? May be we can help.

Comment: i just edited again my question, please see ..

Answer (score 0):

While inside the code (or the adapter), you could try this, get the height of the screen and set the minimumHeight of the linear layout or relative layout to the height that you obtain.

to get the height of the screen follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521076/2683275)