# How do I make the TableLayout fit the screen

Tags: android, android-xml, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to write a simple android application, In the app, I have a blank `TableLayout` in the xml file, and I'm dynamically (through java code) adding `TableRow`s to the table, and Buttons to the table rows. the buttons all have background images.

Everything's perfectly fine, except the size. I want the table to fit the screen but I've had a hard time resizing the whole thing. The best I've been able to do was make the individual buttons smaller by giving them a specific size, which isn't really helpful because of different screen sizes.

I've tried to use the `LayoutParams` and the `MATCH_PARENT` parameters but it doesn't seem to do anything.

My code is something like this:

```
....
TableLayout table = findViewById(R.id.table);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        Button cell = new Button(this);
        cell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_background);
        row.addView(cell);
    }
    table.addView(row);
}
```

How can I make the cells adjust their size according to the screen?

Comment: Do you know how to get the width and height of the screen?

Comment: @LAD I do, but is that the only method? I feel like there should be a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: So you do something like `this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels`? I don't know of a different way, but maybe there is.

Comment: Actually, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6521076/6214491), it shows that you can also use `Point displaySize = new Point(); activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(displaySize);`.

Comment: That seems right, still, If that is the only way to do it dynamically .. then I wonder if there's a way to set the size of the buttons using dp instead of px?